# Order by rand ($foo) in Mysql/PHP Prepared Statement / prevent SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql

I generate a random string with PHP's rand() and store it in session.

Afterwards I want to use it in a Prepared Statement to always get the same random result in a session:

```
SELECT * from foo WHERE id = ? ORDER BY rand ($rand)
```

How can I secure this against SQL injections?

What about

```
settype($rand, "integer");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the relevant php code to the question.

Comment: As I assume the `id = ?` is a prepared statement, use `?` in the `rand ( ? )` bit.

Comment: Thank you! That is the easy solution. Thought (?) isn't possible in rand-statement.

Comment: Its a value arguement. The things you can't do are SQL syntax and table/column/database names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAND arg can be a prepared value too:

```
SELECT * from foo WHERE id = ? ORDER BY rand ( ? )
```

Things that aren't allowed as a prepared value argument are:

- SQL syntax
- database names
- table names
- column names